# Excel data validation formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, validation

I have a table with an input column and have set up two tables with the allowable input values. The correct table depends on the value in a cell at the end of each row. To determine which table is allowed, I set up a data validation formula (like `=if cellatendof row>0, table1, table2`). I tried to drag the data validation down but it would not use a relative reference on the cell it has to check.  So, I manually went into each cell in the column and updated the data validation formula to check the cell for that particular row (like `=if cellatendofrow1>0...  then next =if cellatendofrow2>0`...).

This works but it will not allow for anyone to add or delete a row - or even sort the data - without making the data validation formula off.  Instead of pointing to the new location of the cell, it points to the original row hardcoded.  So if a row is added, now row 1 has moved to row 2 but the formula still looks at the `cellatendofrow1` because it was hardcoded that way, as will all the rest of the rows, and the results will likely be invalid.

Is there a way to make the refernce relative rather than static and move with the rest of the row?

Sorry to say I do not know VB - but could try if that would fix it!

Comment: I have to ask: are you using `A99`, `A$99`, `$A99`, or `$A$99`?

Comment: Thanks @pnuts and @Scott!! The column at the end is always the the same, only the row reference would change. Tied to do a snipit to send a copy of the spreadsheet plus the DV screen but wouldn't paste. The exact formula is =IF($AM$4>0,ATTEND, NOATTEND).  Then going down to the next one would change to  =IF($AM$5>0,ATTEND, NOATTEND) and so on down the list.  From the answer it sounds like I just need to remove the $'s in the formula.  Will go try it - thanks!!  Terry

Answer (score 0):

If Table flag is say in `ColumnC` (always!) then formula as shown below seems to work (using named ranges):

[image: SU479043]